# angularStrap: open directive from modal and pass value from the scope to the directive scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-strap

i am using strapAngular for modal and i having problems in passing the scope to the directive. i search for answer over the internet and didn't found.

```js
$scope.showModal = function(index) {
                var scope = $scope.$new({productItem: "dddddd"});
                var myModal = $modal({
                    templateUrl: "<div modal-view product='productItem' class='modal' tabindex='-1' role='dialog'></div>",
                    persist: true,
                    scope: scope,
                    show: false,
                    html: true,
                    animation: 'am-fade-and-scale',
                    placement: 'center'
                });
                myModal.$promise.then(myModal.show);
            };
```

the directive loads but '$scope.product' is undefined.

Comment: anyone? i am stuck in middle of a project